# programme crashes when trying to cout map value

Tags: c++, debugging, dictionary

I am trying to insert pair values < float,string > into my map class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

    map<float,string> output;

    output.insert(pair<float,string> ( 200.5, "foo" ));
    output.insert(pair<float,string> ( 100.5, "batr" ));

     map<float,string>::iterator mps1;
     map<float,string>::iterator mps2;

       mps1 = output.begin();
       mps2 = output.end();

       while (mps1 != mps2)
       {
           cout<<mps2->first
               <<" "
               <<mps2->second; //crashes here

           mps1++;

       }

     system("PAUSE");
}
```

Using the debugger , it crashes when it does to the following line

```
<<mps2->second;
```

Can someone explain to me , thanks

Comment: You're dereferencing the wrong iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're supposed to access `mps1`, not `mps2`.**

`mps1` is the iterator you're incrementing for use; `mps2` is the "end iterator" which you must not dereference.

It's a pretty basic typo / logic error.

Comment: thanks , overlooked such a simple error